# Scroll problem in tableview in iphone

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am showing some records in tableview. I am seeing vertical scroll is coming on screen but whenever I am clicking for scroll I am getting an SIGABRT error in main() function.

Why this error is coming ?

Thanks

Here are the code which is adding text in table view. This is written in viewdidload() function.

```
-(void) viewDidload() {


    extern NSArray *wallvalue;


     tableList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[wallvalue count]];
    for (NSDictionary *person in wallvalue) {
        NSString *personName = [person objectForKey:@"message"];

      if(![[NSNull null] isEqual:personName] && [personName length])
        {
            [tableList addObject:personName];
              NSLog(personName);
        }
    }

}
```

And my error is occuring in main function which is below.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])

{

    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);

    [pool release];

    return retVal;

}
```

Error is : `Thread EXC_BAD_ACCESS in line (int retval= UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);`

Comment: Show some code. I bet a variable's out of scope, or has been released too early.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is your `numberOfRowsinsection` is more than what your having modal(data).while your trying to scroll the last objects will load in the cells through

`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`  method.
so once check your data while loading the cells once again.while your scrolling  below method will always call

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: sorry I wrote wrong code in function tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath. that's why it was throwing an error. Now this is wroking well.

Comment: Thanks to all of you for support.